# React Navite build faıled

Tags: android, react-native, build

I couldn't solve the error how can I solve it
``
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\azcak\OneDrive\Masaüstü\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
:ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\Users\azcak\OneDrive\Masaüstü\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

PS C:\Users\azcak\OneDrive\Masaüstü\AwesomeProject> npx react-native run-android
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\azcak\OneDrive\Masaüstü\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
:ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\Users\azcak\OneDrive\Masaüstü\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\azcak\OneDrive\Masa�st�\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 413
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\azcak\OneDrive\MasaÃ¼stÃ¼\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: []}Node.js v18.16.0

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 2s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\azcak\OneDrive\Masaüstü\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
:ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\Users\azcak\OneDrive\Masaüstü\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\azcak\OneDrive\Masa�st�\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 413
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

## node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\azcak\OneDrive\MasaÃ¼stÃ¼\AwesomeProject\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: []}Node.js v18.16.0

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 2s

```
at makeError (C:\Users\azcak\OneDrive\Masaüstü\AwesomeProject\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\Users\azcak\OneDrive\Masaüstü\AwesomeProject\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\azcak\OneDrive\Masaüstü\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\azcak\OneDrive\Masaüstü\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:108:9)
```

```
I can't start the application
```

Comment: Please format your question well so people can follow along and understand!

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because of your path. Move your project to english-based path.